# In Spring Boot, How can we load kafka.bootstrap-servers through command line?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, command-line, command-line-arguments

Currently my kafka server id loads through application.properties file. But I want to pass through command line so that when program will start that time of point I can pass server-id.

Right now my program is wokring fine. But if I want to change server-id in future then in that scenario I need to build project again coz I mentioned server-id in property file instead of passing through command line.

My project develop in Java with spring boot.

My apprication.properties

```
#Kafka Config
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers = ***.***.1.160:9092
```

ConsumerConfig

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, 0);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

do How can I pass server-id through command line ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot allows loading properties from different places.
From command line you can use  `java -jar myapp.jar --spring.kafka.bootstrap.servers=...`

The same parameter can be passed through the IDE if you wish

Another possibility is to define an environment variable so that spring boot will read this variable and it will override the default values of the property defind in the `application.properties` file.
All in all spring boot offers pretty advanced options when it comes to configuration, so I suggest reading [this chapter of spring boot documentation] that describes them all[1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: this work like a charm for me. Even run with command line on remote server

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
```

or add it in IDE's run dialog

Comment: Got Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers' in value "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}" error after this code.